# How to Navigate from Tab Page to Normal WPF Page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have four tab pages in Tab controller. I wish to navigate from a tab page to Normal WPF page. For that I am using  `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());` . I am able to navigate to new page that is Page1 but the tab control is still there. Seems Like only stack panel is getting replaced. Is there any way to do it correctly?

Comment: Where are you calling `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());` from?

Comment: In an eventHandler of one of  OnSelectionChanged of ListBox which is present  in tab page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `Navigate` method on the `ListBox`, so only that control is replaced. By setting the `MainWindow`'s `Content`, only the new `Page` will be displayed:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new Page1();
```

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow` is not able to access NavigationService

Comment: Problem is  not solved. It is throwing Null Reference Exception. I guess it's not proper way to navigate